# Solving shortening url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have rewritten my url using htaccess .After navigating to the page, the layout distorts and no value fetched from the database is printed out.This is the main URL

http://www.deffsale.com/personalBusiness/PersonalBusiness.php?item=ladys%20Fashion&page=1

and I'm navigating to this page using this one

http://www.deffsale.com/personalBusiness/all/ladys-Fashion/1

This is my ht-access

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule  ^About-us AboutUs.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^personal-business personalBusiness [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^personalBusiness/all/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+) personalBusiness/PersonalBusiness.php?item=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

please help me solve this because it has been a disturbance past three months

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is? Is `http://www.deffsale.com/personalBusiness/all/ladys-Fashion/1` causing 404?

Comment: It's probably a path issue with your CSS and images related to the rewrite rules.  Add a rule like this: *RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpe?g|png|gif)$ - [L]* which will allow those requests to be passed unmodified.

Comment: No .. it is giving me the only html even the css is not functioning

Comment: Please you can click to see the results

Comment: Let me try it thanks

Comment: will i include the directory because i have copy pasted what you have given to me and still it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include this line just below `<head>` section of your HTML:

```
<base href="/personalBusiness/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL `/personalBusiness/` and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: I have seen the problem .. if i include the dash(-) , (ladys-fashion),the php is not working but if i try another url with one word like tablet ,the php is working ,what might be the problem,please help

Comment: What's the full URL you tried and what exact error did you get?

Comment: This is the initial url http://www.deffsale.com/AllAds/?Ad=Other%20ladys%20Fashion&page=1 .. after shortening http://www.deffsale.com/Other-ladys-Fashion/1 ..This url is not functioning with more than two parameters "Other ladys fashion" however when i use a url with one parameter http://www.deffsale.com/AllAds/?Ad=travel&page=1 after shortening http://www.deffsale.com/travel/1 "travel"  it is working well ..

Comment: What might have been ommitted?

Comment: It is only returning a blank division on the page

Comment: It appears you're asking a new question since none of your rules are for `/Other-ladys-Fashion/` URL. I suggest you create a new question with these details so that we can understand better and answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a path issue with your CSS and images related to the rewrite rules. Add a rule like this before the other rules:

```
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpe?g|png|gif)$ - [L]
```

which will allow those requests to be passed unmodified.

In addition, make sure the URLs for JavaScript, CSS and image files are coded relative to DocumentRoot.  For example if your files are organized like this:

```
/ - index.php
  + css
     + base.css
     + color.css
  + images
     + logo.png
```

The style tags would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/color.css">
```

And images would be:

```
<img src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
```

As the other respondent suggested, you may use a base tag with relative URLs instead.  In that case, you would code the tags like:

```
<base href="/">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/color.css">
```

And images would be:

```
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
```

The difference is that the base tag can be used to set the reference point for the relative URLs.  Bear in mind the base tag will affect all relative URLs on your page.

Comment: will i include the directory because i have copy pasted what you have given to me and still it is not working

Comment: thanks so much it has worked for me but the php code is not functioning.How can i go about it

Comment: I have seen the problem .. if i include the dash(-) , (ladys-fashion),the php is not working but if i try another url with one word like tablet ,the php is working ,what might be the problem,please help

Comment: You need to post the PHP code - possibly in another question